# "When travelling in Australia, guidance is advised."

Tags: verbs, verb-agreement, complex-sentences, ing, when

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

"When travelling in Australia, guidance is advised."

It seems to me the subject is not matching the verb, as if "guidance is travelling".

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["After reviewing ..., it ...": is it grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69854/after-reviewing-it-is-it-grammatical)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatically correct. This is called a [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier), which is a very common and useful feature of a great many languages, including English.

You might still have to avoid it to comply with a particular style guide, or to fix a particular [garden-path sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/are-these-garden-path-sentences-grammatically-correct), [crash blossom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/bbc-man-convicted-of-murdering-his-girlfriend-and-their-10-month-old-daughter), double-entendre or other kinds of involuntary humor. But you cannot dismiss it wholesale on the grounds of pure logic, because language is under no obligation to be logical, and indeed seldom is. (Just think of all the times that we say such stupid things as "[I'm on the bus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus)", or "[it's raining](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining)", or "[he's married with two children](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5839/what-does-i-am-married-with-three-kids-mean)", or "[my mother was born in 1954](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8039/300)".)

Comment: sumelic's link shows that someone disagrees with your interpretation. I wonder who is correct.